# How do I use action or function with List(of Date)

Tags: vb.net

I have a list(of Date) with the dates of US holidays. Whenever a date falls on a weekend it must be moved to Friday or Monday.

I know I can use:

```
    For i As Integer = 0 To HolidayList.Count - 1
        Dim dt As Date = HolidayList(i)
        If dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then
            HolidayList(i) = dt.AddDays(-1)
        End If
        If dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
            HolidayList(i) = dt.AddDays(1)
        End If
    Next
```

But I'm really trying to understand action, delegate, function and lambda; these are all somewhat fuzzy to me. I've used them sometimes and am trying to increase my ability to use them.

Can I increment/decrement the date using an inline function/lambda using HolidayList.ForEach?

```
Dim HolidayList As New List(Of Date)

'I have a function that creates a list of current year's holidays based on the rules 
HolidayList.Add("1/1/2013")
HolidayList.Add("7/4/2013")
HolidayList.Add("12/25/2013")

'saturday holidays are moved to Fri; Sun to Mon
'something like this
'HolidayList.ForEach(action as system.action(of Date))
'HolidayList.ForEach(func(if dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday then dt = dt.AddDays(-1)))
```

Edit: I've checked out the documentation for Action(Of T) Delegate and for List(of T).ForEach, but I haven't been able to put it all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case, you won't be able to do what you want with the `List.ForEach` method (or a For Each loop either).  The problem is that your list stores Dates, which are value types.  This means that the argument to the Action you would pass to ForEach (or the loop variable of a For Each loop) is a copy of the value, thus any new value reassigned will be lost at the end of the delegate call (or loop iteration).  This leaves you with two options; either a standard For loop (For i = 0 to HolidayList.Count - 1) so you can assign back to the list in the loop, or you can build a new list without modifying the old list.  (You could then replace the old list entirely, if desired.)  The latter option would could look something like:

```
Dim allWeekday = From h in HolidayList
                 Select If(h.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday,
                           h.AddDays(-1),
                           If(h.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday,
                              h.AddDays(1),
                              h))
```

or with delgate syntax instead of LINQ:

```
Dim allWeekday = HolidayList.Select(
                    Function (h)
                        If h.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then
                            Return h.AddDays(-1)
                        Else If h.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then
                            Return h.AddDays(1)
                        Else
                            Return h
                        End If
                    End Function)
```

In both versions, `allWeekday` is an `IEnumerable(Of Date)`, which you can convert to a `List(Of Date)` with `ToList()` if needed.

Comment: As one who became intrigued and pursued this just to see how it could work, I'm disappointed that it can't be done this way. However, I now know why my list items weren't updating and it was a fun exercise. Thanks to you both.

Comment: It would be interesting to cater for the Friday or Monday already being a separate holiday. (We'd get that in Australia for ANZAC day falling near Easter, and Xmas and Boxing day (or Proclamation day in SA).)

Comment: @MarkHurd That would certainly be doable, but would require you to have a "SelectWithContext" method that can give you the previous and next dates (assuming they are sorted) or to use the HolidayList in the delegate to check if the day you are about to return already exists (if they are not sorted).  In the SelectWithContext case, you would have to resort the list when you were done.